# How to access the values inside resolved promises?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having difficulty accessing the values from `getPeople(0,4).`

```
function getPeople(start, end) {
    const peopleArray = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      peopleArray.push(
        axios.get(`https://www.testsite.net/api/test/workers/${i}`)
      );
    }
    return peopleArray;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([getData(), getPeople(0, 4)]).then(item => {
      //console.log(item[0].data.orders); //
      setData(item);
      setPersonData(item);
    });
  }, []);
```

`item[0]` works fine.
Here's the result I'm getting when I `console.log(item[1])` How can I access the data?

`item[1]` is an array of promises.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: By using `then` or `await` in an `async` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Well what is `getPeople(0, 4)` doing?

Comment: It looks like `getPeople` is returning another array of promises?  Maybe you need to wrap _another_ `Promise.all` around `item[1]`... but that's heading towards code smell territory

Comment: Are you saying `item[1]` is itself an array of promises? You already know how to access the value of a promise: `.then`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, it is.

Comment: Does `getPeople` return a promise (that returns the array of promises) or just the array of promises directly?

Comment: @WillCain I added the code to the question. It's just an array

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think that may have fixed it.

Comment: [getData(), ...getPeople(0, 4)]

Comment: Now you've edited to show that `getPeople` itself doesn't return a promise, using the spread operator as some comments/answers show is ok and isn't a code smell as per my original comment...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to spread the array returned from `getPeople()` like so:

```js
Promise.all([getData(), ...getPeople(0, 4)]).then(item => {
    console.log(item);
});
```

`Promise.all()` expects an array of `Promise`, you were passing an array containing another array.

Answer (score 0):

The `getPeople` function returns an array of promises.

If you want to await *those* promises in the `Promise.all` call, one option is to:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([getData(), ...getPeople(0, 4)]).then(item => {
      //console.log(item[0].data.orders);  
      console.log(item[1]); // this will effectively output the people 0 object
      setData(item);
      setPersonData(item);
    });
  }, []);
```

The above will receive as `item[0]` the resolved value from the promise of `getData` (which sounds expected already). Then `item[1]` through `item[5]` will be the 5 people objects you seem to be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be made more readable using an async function in useEffect

```
//make sure this actually returns the people rather than a load of promises
async function getPeople(start, end) {

    const peopleArray = [];        
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      let person = await axios.get(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${i}`);
      peopleArray.push(person);
    }
    return peopleArray;

}

//then in useEffect you need to create another async function
useEffect(() => {
    async function getDataAndPersons() {

      const data = await getData();
      setData(data);
      const people = await getPeople(0, 4);
      people.forEach(person => setPersonData(person));

    };
    getDataAndPersons();
}, []);
```